# Blazor Server conditional redirect of authenticated user

Tags: c#, blazor, authorization, blazor-server-side

We are writing CRM system in Blazor Server and we have to implement following scenario.

Authenticated user have to complete profile after registration. Registration is done via ASP.NET identity , after registration user logging in and our goal to restrict all pages until user complete verification.

We were thinking to use Role Based authentication , and restrict CRM pages with

```
[Authorize(Role="VerifiedUser")]
```

and Verification page with

```
[Authorize]
```

only

But it's completely unclear how to redirect the authenticated user without Role 'Verified' to Verification page.

Our App.razor

```
<Fluxor.Blazor.Web.StoreInitializer />

<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">

                <NotAuthorized>
                    @if (context.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated != true)
                    {
                        <HxRedirectTo Uri="@($"/Identity/Account/Login")" />
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       
                    }
                </NotAuthorized>

            </AuthorizeRouteView>

        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Is there something like  section ?

Another approach was to override the OnInitialize on MainLayout and put the redirect logic there,
but this Method is not called when internal navigation happening.

Could anyone point us to proper way of implementation of this task. Thank you.

We've tried overriding the OnInitialize attribute in Main Layout.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using [JSInterop](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet). Based on [this GitHub discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13709#issuecomment-551376611) you can create a component, which calls the JS code to instruct a redirect from the browser.

`RedirectToHomePage` component

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

Redirecting in 3 seconds...

@code {
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            var uri = NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/");
            int redirectAfterMs = 3000;

            await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("startRedirectToUri", uri, redirectAfterMs);
        }
    }
}
```

`App.razor`

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <RedirectToHomePage />
                </NotAuthorized>
                ...
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        ...
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

`redirect.js`

```js
function startRedirectToUri(uri, redirectAfterMs) {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        window.location = uri;
    }, redirectAfterMs);
}
```